# What does "But lay off his looks, okay, Donald?" mean?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, colloquialisms

In this issue of "The O'Reilly Factor" Bill O'Reilly [says at the end](http://uk.businessinsider.com/bill-oreilly-donald-trump-petty-stuff-2015-9?r=US&IR=T):

> "But lay off his looks, okay, Donald?"

**My question**
What does this phrase mean?

Comment: It means don't talk about how attractive he is or isn't.

Comment: @Robusto If you made this an answer with some background information I would accept it - Thank you.

Comment: Either of the two answers below should serve your purpose.

Comment: On several occasions, Mr. Trump has commented negatively on the appearance of people he does not like or has disputes with. In most cases, these negative assessments have been directed toward women. This statement appears to be a bit tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 1):

**"But lay off his looks, okay, Donald?"**

Ive never seen a picture of Biden but Bill O"Reilly is advising Donald Trump **not to make any reference to** Biden's looks.

> lay off - to leave undisturbed, avoid.

Answer (score 1):

*Lay off*, when used as an informal command, means:

> 3. (*Slang*) To stop doing something; quit.  ([FreeDictionary)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/lay+off)

When you are advising someone to "Lay off (some other person)", normally it means that someone has been picking on some other person, insulting him, giving him a hard time, being mean to him, or the like; and that you think this behavior should stop.

When the thing to be laid off is more specific, it means that the objectionable behavior is also more specific.  So, *Lay off his looks* = *stop insulting the way he looks*.